# My localStorage is overridden on refresh, how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have some React code. It's a very simple app. The problem I have is that my `localStorage` is emptied on refresh and the todo's are gone.

How do I make it, so that I can read from `localStorage` and show the todo's on refresh as well?

Thanks!

I'll post the full code below.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";

export default function Home() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState();
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todoList));
  }, [todoList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
    setTodoList(newArray);
  }, []);

  const formSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setTodoList([
      ...todoList,
      {
        id: todoList.length + 1,
        name: inputValue,
      },
    ]);
    setInputValue("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <form action="" onSubmit={formSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name=""
          id=""
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Verzenden" />
      </form>

      <ul className="list">
        {todoList?.map((item) => {
          return <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Set `localStorage.getItem("todos")` initially. You are not using the saved localStorage value. `const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState({localStorage value goes here});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the component renders for the first time it gets an empty array as todoList because you set todoList in useEffect and useEffect execute after completing the render of the component. So you have to set the local storage value as a state if there exists any if not then it will be an empty array.

```
const storedTodoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState(storedTodoList || []);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.